# Python code failing due to date and time in HTTP post

Tags: python, json, post

I am trying to report malicious IPs to Virustotal through comments.

This code works:

```
import requests
#import datetime
#import time

ip = open('/home/pi/upload.log', 'r')
#today = datetime.datetime.now()
for x in ip:
  try:
    ip = x.rstrip()
    url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/" + ip + "/comments"
    print(url)
    print(ip)
    payload = '{"data":{"type":"comment","attributes":{"text":"This IP was carrying out SSH bruteforce attack"}}}'
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-apikey': 'api key here'
}
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    print(response)
    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
    time.sleep(16)
  except:
    pass
```

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
import requests
import datetime
import time

ip = open('/home/pi/upload.log', 'r')
today = datetime.datetime.now()
for x in ip:
  try:
    ip = x.rstrip()
    url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/" + ip + "/comments"
    print(url)
    print(ip)
    payload = {"data":{"type":"comment","attributes":{"text":'This IP was carrying out SSH bruteforce attack on '  + today.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")}}}
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-apikey': 'api key here'
}
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    print(response)
    print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
    time.sleep(16)
  except:
    pass
```

The error I get is:

```
<Response [400]>
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequestError",
        "message": "Malformed JSON"
    }
}
https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/ip_addresses/5.182.39.61/comments
```

I am not sure where I'm going wrong. Giving date as part of threat intelligence helps others who are looking up IP reputation.

What changes do I need to make for the code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second code, you are not converting the payload to a JSON string:

```
import json
...
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = json.dumps(payload))
...
```